# How to split a larger-than-disk file using Azure ML?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ml-pipelines, azure-ml-component

Using Azure ML components and pipelines: How to split a larger-than-disk (PGN) file into shards and save the output files to a designated `uri_folder` on a blob storage? Feel free to provide any best-practices to achieve the goal.

I set up a component and a pipeline with the following `yml` configuration files:

**Component**

```
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/commandComponent.schema.json
name: split_file_to_shards
display_name: Split file to shards
version: 0.0.9
type: command

inputs:
  input_data_file:
    type: uri_file
    mode: ro_mount

outputs:
  output_data_dir:
    type: uri_folder
    mode: rw_mount

environment:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu20.04:latest

code: ./
command: >-
  split -u -n r/100 --verbose ${{inputs.input_data_file}} ${{outputs.output_data_dir}}
```

**Pipeline**

```
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/pipelineJob.schema.json
type: pipeline
experiment_name: sample-experiment

compute: azureml:vm-cluster-cpu

inputs:
  input_data_file:
    type: uri_file
    path: azureml:larger-than-disk-file@latest

outputs:
  output_data_dir:
    type: uri_folder
    path: azureml://datastores/<blob_storage_name>/paths/<path_to_folder>/

jobs:
  split_pgn_to_shards:
    type: command
    component: azureml:split_file_to_shards@latest
    inputs:
      input_data_file: ${{parent.inputs.input_data_file}}
    outputs:
      output_data_dir: ${{parent.outputs.output_data_dir}}
```

**Run commands**

```
> az ml component create -f component.yml
> az ml job create -f pipeline.yml
```

I expect Azure ML to mount the input file on a `ro_mount` and write the processed files to `rw_mount`. I understood the remaining options `download` and `upload` to actively download the file to the VM's local disk and upload the files after processing to the mount, respectively, which is not what I want.

The command argument `-u` in `split` is used for unbuffered write to output.

From the monitoring Network I/O I unexpectedly see the file being downloaded to disk.
In addition, I get the following error from the component:

```
Disk full while running job. Please consider reducing amount of data accessed, or upgrading VM SKU.
Total space: 6958 MB, available space: 1243 MB (under AZ_BATCH_NODE_ROOT_DIR).
```

Comment: Did you checked answer for the same Qs on QnA platform?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1287222/how-to-split-a-larger-than-disk-file-using-azure-m